# Lazy load for "magnific.popup.js"

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup, page-load-time

Is there a way of initializing the magnific.popup.js after the page loads?

I do not prefer loading it with the rest of the scripts as I only need it, and trigger the popup on a button click.

The ultimate goal is to not see it listed on the report of PageSpeed Insights, what would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your script dynamically.

```
function **functionname**(){   
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    
    script.setAttribute('src',**path or url script**);
    
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Call the function as you need the script

Comment: Can I initialize an object from the external script as soon as I call the function in this case?
OR should I wait and make sure that the script is loaded first? If it is the latter, how can we make sure of it?

Comment: You have to be sure external script is loaded. Async request might be useful in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests